# Processing array of objects using unshift and pop sequence

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a array in which I am pushing objects, I am using `array.unshift(object)` to add the object to beginning of the array.

I am retrieving element from the array using `var object = array.pop()` which is removing object from the end of the array.

Now my array is getting filled in very fast there are multiple objects in this array are getting pushed every second. and every time a new element is getting pushed in the array I need to pop array and process it and send it further which takes time.

So is it the good way to call a method after a interval of 1 second every time and then pop one element from the array and process it, but if it takes more than 1 second to process the object from array, then next call to process method should also be delayed, in short process array method should be called after every interval but should wait if previous call was still processing.

What is the better way of implementing it?

Sample code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('DataService', ['$rootScope', 'UpdateService', function($rootScope, UpdateService)
{
    // To store array of JSON updates    
    var arrayOfUpdates = [];

    // To store callbacks to which we need to send updates after processing 
    var arrayofCallbacks = [];

    // Method is getting called when there are updates from "UpdateService" server 
    this.onDataUpdated = function (jsonObj)
    {
        // This will add this object in the array
        arrayOfUpdates.unshift(jsonObj);
    }

    // This method will process data and send it further 
    function processData()
    {
         // Get the last element from the array 
         var jsonObj = arrayOfUpdates.pop();

         // Now process this JSON data  
         var data = doSomeCalculations(jsonObj); 

         // There can be 10-20 callbacks at a time   
         for(var index=0;index<arrayofCallbacks.length;index++)
         {
               var object = arrayofCallbacks[index]; 
               object.onUpdatedData(data);
         }       

         // After this pop next element and process and send to registered callbacks 
         // I can not call "processData()" again as it can create loop 
         // Also calling it after interval might call it when it has not completed processing 
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with promise?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? How is this array being filled in? Which type of processing are you doing? The more specific you are the easier it is to help. Also if you can add some more code would help

Comment: Why do you want/have to wait a second before processing the next item?

Comment: @cracker: Yes I am going to promise but issue is same method is getting called before it has finished processing.

Comment: @Matt Way: I will need to wait for seconds as in case if array that I want to process can be empty and calling recursive (same method again) might create problem, and it might go in infinite loop.

Comment: @wilsotobianco: For sample code I have currently implemented only array.unshift(jsonObj); which is adding elements in the array. These elements (JSON Objects) are received from one of the other service in the application in the form of callback. And I am thinking on how to process elements of the array one by one. When I say processing I am getting one element from array doing some calculations based on JSON data in the object and then sending it to callbacks registered with the service, these callbacks are nothing but controllers which further process this data.

Comment: Cool. Can you add the code to the question? May be a small example

Comment: @A_user http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/ here you go

Comment: @wilsotobianco: Please see my updated question with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are implementing a queue. You want to be able to push to the back of the queue (`unshift`), and this happens potentially quite quickly. You also want to process items at the front of the queue (`pop`), but the processing stage takes time. My guess is that these processes are operating asynchronously, so you are ending up with many processing steps occurring at the same time, and encountering some race like conditions with your data.

Unless you need to actively check what is in the queue (outside of your processing functions), I would suggest removing the queue all together, and using promise chaining in place of the queue.

To do this, whenever your incoming data event is triggered, instead of using `unshift()`, you simply pass the data to your promise chain which will not execute until all the previous processing has completed. Some pseudo-js:

```
// the promise chain (initialised to automatically trigger then())
var worker = Promise.resolve();

// handle incoming data
function incomingData(data){
    // process this data AFTER all other processing and update the chain
    worker = worker.then(last => processData(data));
}

// process data
function processData(data){
    // do work on the data and return a promise if work is async
    return ...
}
```

---

Update: The first thing I suggest would be reading up on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). But I will do a more in depth explanation below:

1. Setup the worker. By setting a variable to `Promise.resolve()` you are essentially creating a promise that has already resolved (completed). Think of this as an empty queue that has completed all the work it needs to do.
2. Update the promise chain when you get new incoming data. If you put a function inside then, like `myPromise.then(myFunc)`, myFunc won't run until `myPromise` has been resolved, which is up to the programmer. It might be resolved after some api call has returned, or after some other work. You can think of the update to worker as follows:

   Imagine running `processData(data)` every time new data arrives, passing in the received `data`. Now imagine not being able to run the function until the previous one completes. This is what is happening in the code above. So yes, the incoming data is stored.

Comment: Not clear to me how it exactly works and how the execution flow is. what does `Promise.resolve()` does also what `worker.then(last => processData(data)` is doing. Also will it store all the data received in `incomingData(data)` till it is not processed?

Comment: I have added more information to the answer, but what you are asking really does require a basic understanding of promises, which I suggest you read up on (link in update).

Comment: "Now imagine not being able to run the function until the previous one completes. This is what is happening in the code above. So yes, the incoming data is stored." -- But if we store the data how the `processData` will be invoked as we are calling `worker.then(last => processData(data)` in `incomingData`. Is it that till the queue is not empty Angular keeps calling processData in sequence.

Comment: Exactly. It puts one function with the data behind the previous one, and doesn't execute the function until the previous one completes. This is an example of why promises are really nice.

Comment: Thanks for the details, What need to be returned in the "processData(data)", will it possible to create small working example.

Comment: If you are doing synchronous work with the data, then return what ever you like. But if you are doing any asynchronous work, like calling an api, or uploading a file, updating a database, etc, then you need to return a promise. I highly suggest reading some promise tutorials, as they will be a regular tool in your coding toolkit. Heres one plucked from google: http://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/

Comment: I guess it is very hard for me to digest, will think of using some other way for this implementation. I am not able to find a very simple in detailed explanation for Promise and related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your time taking tasks are of asynchronous nature you might come up with a recursive asynchronous flow control with promises as follows;

We are unshifting a random number in-between 1 and 10 to `arr` array every 250ms while popping out one every 1000ms. The defined limit is 10 items and once we reach the `limit` value unshifting stops.

```js
function doStgAndPop(a){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { var id = setTimeout(_ => a.length > 0 ? resolve(a.pop()) : reject(id),1000)});
}

function doStgAndUnshift(a){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { var id = setTimeout(_ => a.length < limit ? (a.unshift(~~(Math.random()*10+1)),resolve(a))
                                                                                     : reject(id),250)});
}

function runnerPop(a){
  doStgAndPop(a).then(v => (console.log("pop out resulted:",v),runnerPop(a)))
                .catch(e => (console.log("array is now empty"),clearSetTimeout(e)));
}
function runnerUnshift(a){
  doStgAndUnshift(a).then(v => (console.log("new array after unshift",JSON.stringify(v)),runnerUnshift(a)))
                    .catch(e => (console.log("array limit:",limit,"reached"),clearSetTimeout(e)));
}

var limit = 10,
      arr = [];

runnerUnshift(arr);
runnerPop(arr);
```

I am using native ES6 promises. `doStgAndPop` returns a promise and runs an asynchronous function (`setTimeout`) which hangs for 1000ms and pops an item from `arr` if `arr.length > 0` or rejects the operation.. `doStgAndUnshift` is very similar but unshifts an item every 250ms up until the limit is reached and once the limit is reached it rejects. `runnerPop` and `runnerUnshift` are recursive functions which invoke `doStgAndPop` and `doStgAndUnshift` respectively and receive a promise. At the `then` stages we recursively invoke runner functions and at the `catch` stages we finalize the operation.

Comment: I am completely new to Angular Promise and how it works so it will be hard for me to understand this code flow.

Comment: @A_user I have just added some explanation at the bottom of my answer. I hope it helps.